# read and write geotiffs bigger than memory?

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, big-data

The geotiff format is a versatile and easy to understand file format. The only limitation is when I try to do raster calculations I prefer to use GDAL (over ArcPy) which comes with the limitation that you read the data in the computer's memory.

My objective is to do raster calculations such as setting all values below a threshold to a NoData value.

Somebody shared a python library called [DASK](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) with me. Can somebody explain how to open, calculate and write geotiff files bigger than your memory?

The problem is how GDAL stores the array in the computer memory

```
try:
    from osgeo import ogr, osr, gdal
except:
    sys.exit('ERROR: cannot find GDAL/OGR modules')
# Enable GDAL/OGR exceptions
gdal.UseExceptions()
import os
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

INPUTPATH = os.path.join('Path to store the geotiffs')

OUTPUTPATH = os.path.join('Path to store the output geotiffs')


def readFile(filename):
    filehandle = gdal.Open(filename)
    band1 = filehandle.GetRasterBand(1)
    geotransform = filehandle.GetGeoTransform()
    geoproj = filehandle.GetProjection()
    Z = band1.ReadAsArray() # Can this be avoided?
    xsize = filehandle.RasterXSize
    ysize = filehandle.RasterYSize
    filehandle = None
    return xsize,ysize,geotransform,geoproj,Z

def writeFile(filename,geotransform,geoprojection,data):
    (x,y) = data.shape
    format = "GTiff"
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)
    # you can change the dataformat but be sure to be able to store negative values including -9999
    dst_datatype = gdal.GDT_Float32
    dst_ds = driver.Create(filename,y,x,1,dst_datatype, [ 'COMPRESS=LZW' ])
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(-9999)
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(data)
    dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
    dst_ds.SetProjection(geoprojection)
    dst_ds = None
    return 1

files = os.listdir(INPUTPATH)

for oneFile in files:
    print oneFile
    InputBaseName = oneFile.split('.')[0]
    [xsize, ysize, geotransform, geoproj, Z] = readFile(os.path.join(INPUTPATH, oneFile))
    Z[Z<-9000] = -9999
    writefilename = os.path.join(OUTPUTPATH,(InputBaseName+".tif"))
    writeFile(writefilename, geotransform, geoproj, Z)

print "Done"
```

This link is useful but I can't seem to find a way to read the array from the geotiff in dask. Any tips/tricks?

Comment: No **sane** raster library would ***require*** the entire raster be in memory.  This seems more likely to be an issue of incorrect use.  Please format your Python code so it could execute.

Comment: Read the image block by block or line by line... look at band1.ReadRaster http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html... I've used this for multi-terrabyte rasters on a line-by-line basis successfully. Just remember that the blocks are in *cell* coordinates from the upper left and not world coordinates.

Comment: done. My raster is a float 64 on 30s degree resolution 21600,43200

Comment: But you're writing GDT_Float32, you can't write a double array to a float memory block... you would need to convert each element from double to float before writing or change your datatype to GDT_Float64 on creation. If you have arcpy you could have done all this with a Con(Float statement - assuming you have spatial analyst extension.

Comment: Thank you for these comments. I am still struggling how to perform algebra (in python IDE) on these scanlines or blocks (getting lost in GDAL docs), can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

You might be able to do your processing with the [gdal_calc.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html) utility, which has block-level processing (not whole file processing). For example, this command should do the same thing your program does, using Numpy's [where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) command:

```
gdal_calc.py -A input1.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="where(A < -9000, -9999, A)" \
             --co=COMPRESS=LZW --NoDataValue=-9999 --type=Float32
```

(This is one command wrapped on two lines. Windows users via OSGeo4W Shell will need to replace `gdal_calc.py` with `gdal_calc` and replace continue line character `\` with `^`)

However, if you need to do something more specific, you can [see how the source code for `gdal_calc.py` works](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_calc.py).